# Prime number expressible as $2^2+3^3+5^5+7^7+11^{11}+\cdots$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I found that $2^2+3^3=31$ and $31$ is a prime, also $2^2+3^3+5^5+7^7$ is a prime. After these the only prime I found is $2^2+3^3+5^5+7^7+11^{11}+\cdots+83^{83}+89^{89}$. And I've checked $p(n)$ up to $1009$, but I couldn't find another prime of the form 
$$
2^2+3^3+5^5+7^7+11^{11}+\cdots+p(n-1)^{p(n-1)}+p(n)^{p(n)}.
$$
Is there any other prime with that form?

Comment: Did you use a supercomputer?

Comment: No,I calculated it with my old Laptop

Comment: No analytical way can I imagine for that. Seems you only need a more powerful hardware. As prime numbers grow, they get diluted.

Comment: Did you make sure that the numbers, when being calculated, didn't rollover? (I guess you are aware that standard integer types are stored using 16 bits, so calculating anything too much will be cut)

Comment: @Wojowu,that last prime is less than 176 digits.

Comment: If you are using standard int type, then calculating even 11^11 already gives you 285311670611, which 70 times above the storage capabilities of standard int. If you are using long ints, then already 23^23 is above what you can store.

Comment: Partially related: https://oeis.org/A061789.

Comment: Even if you use some arbitrary precision package, then number of size 1000^1000 has 3000 digits, and checking it for primality would be absurdly hard.

Comment: @Wojowu: I checked the big one on Wolfram ([see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+%282^2%2B3^3%2B5^5%2B7^7%2B11^11%2B13^13%2B17^17%2B19^19%2B23^23%2B29^29%2B31^31%2B37^37%2B41^41%2B43^43%2B47^47%2B53^53%2B59^59%2B61^61%2B67^67%2B71^71%2B73^73%2B79^79%2B83^83%2B89^89%29+prime%3F)). It is prime.

Comment: @Wojowu why do you claim checking primality is absurdly hard for a 3000 digit number; the largest known prime has more than 17 million digits. (Factoring such a number would be a different matter though.)

Comment: @quid Largest known prime, which you mention, is a Mersenne number, and this type of numbers has particularly fast (time complexity $O(\log(n)^3)$). Testing primality of general numbers is much slower (I believe fastest algorithm is $O(\log(n)^6)$).

Comment: @Wojowu this is not really an answer to my question (though I admit you have some point re MP). Yet checking https://primes.utm.edu/top20/index.php you will find plenty of primes of varied forms with a lot more then 3000 digits. What's more for the larger numbers here one does not need a proof of primeness as they seem in fact composite which is quiet easier  (However, one should be cautious that when just asking a CAS they might not prove the number prime but just test.)

Comment: @Wojowu I think you are seriously underestimating the power of modern hardware, even my phone, with the [J interpreter](http://www.jsoftware.com/) for android, can tell you that $p(89)$ is composite! (also, it's pretty common for int to be 32bit wide, and most modern processor have hardware support for 128 or 256bit integer arithmetics, with the AVX512 for 512bit integers scheduled to start being supported this year).

Comment: @Wojowu The rabin-miller-test is very fast. If the result is composite, this result is always true. If the result is prime, the number is very probable prime (if enough bases were checked). PROVING the primality is much harder, but can be done with numbers of a few thousand digits.

Comment: @Alessandro $p(89)=2^2+3^3+5^5+...+89^{89}$ is prime!

Comment: @peter you're right, rereading my comment I think I meant prime and not composite (also because I just checked and my phone takes longer to test $p(89)$ than near numbers, so I guess I choose $89$ on purpose)

Answer (score 6):

The standard heuristic for such things is this.

Given a (growing) sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ where there is no apparent reason for a number in there to be prime or not consider (as the probability that a number of a certain rough size $N$ is prime is $(\log N)^{-1}$)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ \log a_n} $$

If this converges there should be only finitely many primes in your sequence.

Let us do this for you sequence. We have that $a_n \ge  p_n^{p_n}$ and as $p_n \sim n \log n $ let us estimate $a_n$ as   $(n \log n)^{n \log n}$ so $\log a_n$ is about $n  (\log n)^2 $ (I drop all lower order terms).

The series $$\sum_{n =2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n (\log n)^2 } $$ 
converges, so we expect only finitely many primes in that sequence.

It thus is conceivable you found all of them, but there is likely no way to prove this with current "technology." 
Note that there is also no proof yet that there are only finitely many Fermat primes, which should be rather easier since that sequence grows faster and is generally easier to handle.

Comment: The expected number of remaining primes of that type is about 0.2, so finding another isn't particularly unlikely. But I agree with your heuristic, failing a conspiracy there should be only finitely many.

Comment: I agree it  is not very unlikely there is another one either. All I meant to say that it would not be a surprise if there is no other, as opposed to say Wieferich primes, where there really should be (infinitely many) others.

Comment: No disagreement here, just thought I'd share my calculations with you.

Answer (score 1):

If a prime number of the form $$2^2+3^3+5^5+7^7+...+p^p$$ with $p>89$ exists,
$p$ must be greater than $8731$ and the number must have more than $34,000$ digits.

The candidates for $2^2+3^3+5^5+7^7+...+p^p$ (no prime factor $\le 104,729$) upto $p=10^5$ are :

```
[7, 43, 89, 107, 193, 229, 251, 397, 433, 683, 701, 971, 1013, 1109, 1193, 1223, 1231, 1277, 1459, 1493, 1511, 1531, 1871, 2143, 2161, 2213, 2543, 2551, 2617, 2851, 2861, 3023, 3541, 3923, 3989, 4093, 4447, 4597, 4783, 4813, 5003, 5227, 5333, 5351, 5437, 5563, 5591, 5779, 5839, 6173, 7103, 7253, 7541, 7549, 7741, 7757, 7873, 8353, 8543, 8699, 8731, 8861, 9323, 9397, 9413, 9439, 9613, 9623, 9631, 9743, 9781, 9871, 10061, 10139, 10333, 10429, 10729, 10847, 10867, 11383, 11941, 11959, 12119, 12239, 12277, 12497, 12619, 12653, 12923, 13033, 13723, 13759, 13933, 13967, 14221, 14249, 14341, 14461, 14557, 14779, 14851, 14887, 15149, 15319, 15401, 15443, 15727, 15739, 15803, 16087, 16097, 16189, 16447, 17093, 17383, 17419, 17551, 17737, 17909, 18899, 18919, 19219, 19373, 19417, 19441, 19553, 19583, 19813, 19919, 20143, 20663, 21407, 22391, 22543, 22691, 22871, 22921, 23561, 23567, 23603, 23789, 24007, 24077, 24103, 24137, 24203, 24359, 24373, 24421, 24473, 25153, 25981, 26729, 26839, 26927, 26987, 27059, 27277, 27487, 27803, 27851, 27947, 28001, 28499, 28579, 28753, 29303, 29587, 29741, 29759, 29789, 29837, 29881, 30011, 30097, 30319, 30689, 31393, 31849, 32089, 32257, 32503, 32971, 33113, 33181, 33349, 33391, 33427, 33521, 33773, 33997, 34141, 34667, 34693, 34721, 34847, 35257, 35419, 35603, 36299, 36709, 37087, 37879, 38371, 38603, 38707, 39343, 39373, 40427, 40763, 40787, 41149, 41201, 41257, 41593, 41897, 41911, 42089, 42463, 42557, 43037, 43067, 43451, 43661, 43691, 43717, 44101, 44179, 44537, 44819, 45197, 45337, 45757, 45823, 46261, 46399, 46933, 47093, 47221, 47293, 47629, 47659, 47699, 47981, 48299, 48371, 48479, 48767, 49117, 49537, 49633, 49853, 49993, 50101, 50273, 50321, 50753, 50789, 51287, 51511, 51871, 52553, 52691, 52883, 53161, 53239, 53309, 53327, 54037, 54139, 54311, 55103, 55147, 55171, 55439, 55987, 56369, 56383, 56629, 56783, 56809, 57331, 57559, 57923, 58013, 58129, 58337, 58379, 58427, 58679, 59359, 59669, 60103, 60127, 60169, 60649, 60887, 61483, 61861, 62233, 62347, 62473, 62653, 62861, 62939, 62983, 63067, 63197, 63439, 63671, 63737, 63853, 64067, 64171, 64237, 64579, 64661, 64763, 65089, 65147, 65407, 65449, 65951, 65983, 66643, 67121, 67169, 67531, 67763, 68281, 68881, 69557, 69763, 69991, 70451, 70501, 70573, 70627, 71209, 71237, 71633, 71707, 71741, 71821, 71879, 71887, 72341, 72937, 73091, 73459, 73643, 73973, 74027, 74149, 74203, 74363, 74653, 74891, 74941, 75017, 75109, 76597, 76847, 76919, 77317, 77339, 77369, 77699, 78301, 78583, 78607, 78781, 78877, 78929, 79193, 79241, 79393, 79433, 79609, 79769, 80147, 80513, 80629, 80761, 80963, 81083, 81409, 81569, 82037, 82301, 82339, 82393, 83117, 83311, 83341, 83621, 83701, 84503, 84967, 85009, 86413, 86693, 86851, 87013, 87071, 87151, 87277, 87629, 88007, 88321, 88379, 88547, 88609, 89209, 89393, 89431, 89477, 89561, 89597, 89627, 89939, 89983, 90397, 90709, 91457, 91631, 91961, 92033, 92179, 92233, 92363, 92801, 92927, 93047, 93133, 93887, 94063, 94307, 94793, 94873, 95561, 95621, 95701, 95957, 95971, 96149, 96167, 96323, 96461, 96589, 96667, 96697, 96823, 96847, 96979, 97021, 97073, 97649, 97871, 98347, 98429, 98621, 98993, 99347, 99377, 99719]
```

I used this PARI/GP-program for the search :

```
? s=0;p=1;while(p<10^5,p=nextprime(p+1);s=s+p^p;if(gcd(s,u)==1,print1(p," ");if(
ispseudoprime(s,1)==1,print;print("********************",p);print)))
7
********************7

43 89
********************89

107 193 229 251 397 433 683 701 971 1013 1109 1193 1223 1231 1277 1459 1493 1511
 1531 1871 2143 2161 2213 2543 2551 2617 2851 2861 3023 3541 3923 3989 4093 4447
 4597 4783 4813 5003 5227 5333 5351 5437 5563 5591 5779 5839 6173 7103 7253 7541
 7549 7741 7757 7873 8353 8543 8699 8731 8861 9323
```

Comment: I continued upto $p=9439$, still not finding a prime. So, the minimum number of the digits of the desired prime is greater than $37,500$.